# Jquery Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The below form uses Google Autocomplete API which takes the input "autocomplete" and changes it to separate items in a second form (which is hidden unless a user clicks "Can't find an address?". This all works great, however I am using JQuery to validate that each field has data in it (by changing background to green), and this does not work correctly. It works when I individually input into each field and makes them green, but neither autocomplete input or the individual inputs turn green when this happens. 
Html

```
<div id="locationField">
    <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Begin typing an address"
               onFocus="geolocate()" type="text" class="form-control"/>
    <sup><a id="newClientAddressFormLink">Can't find an address?</a></sup>
</div>

<div id="newClientAddressForm" style="display:none;">
    <div id="address">
        <div>
            <input type="text" data-street-number-id="0" class="form-control" id="street_number" maxlength="10" placeholder="Number*" />
            <div id="StreetNumberValidation" class="alert alert-danger complaint-validation" role="alert" style="display: none; max-width: 280px;"><strong>Number</strong> required!</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" data-street-name-id="0" class="form-control" id="route" maxlength="50" placeholder="Street*" />
            <div id="StreetNameValidation" class="alert alert-danger complaint-validation" role="alert" style="display: none; max-width: 280px;"><strong>Street</strong> required!</div>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

JQuery

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('change keyup blur input', "#autocomplete", function () {
        if (this.value.length > 25)
        {
            checkStreetNumberLength(document.getElementById("#street_number"));
            checkStreetNameLength(document.getElementById("#route"));
            $("#autocomplete").css("background-color", "#dff0d8");
        }    
    });
    // Street Number (ID is from Google Autocomplete API)
    $(document).on('change keyup blur input', "#street_number", function () {
        checkStreetNumberLength(this);
    });
    // Street Name (ID is from Google Autocomplete API)
    $(document).on('change keyup blur input', "#route", function () {
        checkStreetNameLength(this);
    });
});

var checkStreetNumberLength = function (fn) {
    if (fn.value.length < 1) {
        $("#street_number").css("background-color", "#fff");
    }
    else {
        $("#street_number").css("background-color", "#dff0d8");
    }
}
var checkStreetNameLength = function (fn) {
    if (fn.value.length < 5) {
        $("#route").css("background-color", "#fff");
    }
    else {
        $("#route").css("background-color", "#dff0d8");
    }
}
```

It returns a `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null` error on `if (fn.value.length < 1)` and `if (fn.value.length < 5)`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a good idea to mix DOM and jQuery, especially not if you mix the selectors.

```
document.getElementById("#street_number")
```

should not have a # like jQuery or querySelector. Instead use jQuery and pass the jQuery object:

```
checkStreetNumberLength($("#street_number"));
checkStreetNameLength($("#route"));
```

then when you pass, use the passed:

```
var checkStreetNumberLength = function ($obj) { // jQuery object passed
  $obj.css("background-color", $obj.val().length < 1?"#fff":"#dff0d8");
}

var checkStreetNameLength = function ($obj) {
  $obj.css("background-color", $obj.val().length < 5?"#fff":"#dff0d8");
}
```

You can also just trigger an event and get rid of some code:

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on('change keyup blur input', "#autocomplete", function() {
    if (this.value.length > 25) {
      $("#street_number").change(); // trigger change
      $("#route").change();
      $("#autocomplete").css("background-color", "#dff0d8");
    }
  });
  // Street Number (ID is from Google Autocomplete API)
  $(document).on('change keyup blur input', "#street_number", function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", $(this).val().length < 1?"#fff":"#dff0d8");
  });
  // Street Name (ID is from Google Autocomplete API)
  $(document).on('change keyup blur input', "#route", function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", $(this).val().length < 5?"#fff":"#dff0d8");
  });
});
```

Comment: Awesome! Exactly what I was looking for. Im not able to do the inline length check as i have other code i need to run when it is validated but now i know if i need it! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

**`document.getElementById` doesn't use the #.**

Also, alternatively, since you're using jQuery: `document.getElementById("#street_number")` could also be written as `$("#street_number")[0]`. jQuery returns an array-like wrapper with the native DOM element at the first index.

https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-pull-a-native-dom-element-from-a-jquery-object/

Comment: Awesome! Helped me alot! Thanks